# Mouse Events : FF and Chrome observation

Tags: javascript, ajax

Below is my javascript.

Init() getting called on `onload`. Different observation in `firefox` and `chrome`

In `firefox` : It is working fine.Getting `Changed-sending` alert if any event ( mouse move, up, down ) occur and getting alert `Not Changed` if no event occurs.

But in `chrome` : I always get  `Changed-sending` alert irrespective of if i don't move mouse.What is the issue here.

Plz help.

```
var state="false";
function Init () {
if (document.addEventListener) {  
alert("here");
document.addEventListener ("mousedown", function () {ChangeState ()}, false);
document.addEventListener ("mouseup", function () {ChangeState ()}, false);
document.addEventListener ("mousemove", function () {ChangeState ()}, false);
document.addEventListener ("keydown", function () { ChangeState ()}, false);
document.addEventListener ("scroll", function () {ChangeState ()}, false);
}
setInterval(function(){ myFunction();},7000);
}


function myFunction () {
if(state=="true"){
var xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET","http://www.google.com", true);
alert('Changed-sending');
xhr.send();
state="false";
}else{
alert('Not Changed');
}
}

function ChangeState () {
state="true";
}

function getXMLHttpRequest() {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
return new XMLHttpRequest();
}else {  
try { 
return new(ActiveXObject)("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
} catch (e) {
alert("aaa22333"); 
log("browser doesn support AJAX."); 
return null;  } }  }
```

Comment: Why are you using booleans as strings?

Comment: @ elclanrs  : hmn..i ll correct it.Could that be issue. ? I don't think but I ll try

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: @HMR : No errors.Its running fine but behaviors are different in  FF and chrome.You can also try it.

Comment: @elclanrs : I tried it with boolean but same issue.

Comment: maybe because you're using alerts, every time you click on the ok button it registers as key down. I've changed the alerts to console.log because I find alerting irritating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no problem with the code you provided even without changing the "true" and "false", did have to add a call to Init or nothing would happen. When comparing someting to be true or false I would use === instead of ==.

```
var state=false;
function Init () {
 if (document.addEventListener) {  
  document.addEventListener ("mousedown", function () {ChangeState ()}, false);
  document.addEventListener ("mouseup", function () {ChangeState ()}, false);
  document.addEventListener ("mousemove", function () {ChangeState ()}, false);
  document.addEventListener ("keydown", function () { ChangeState ()}, false);
  document.addEventListener ("scroll", function () {ChangeState ()}, false);
}
setInterval(function(){ myFunction();},1000);
}
Init();

function myFunction () {
 if(state===true){
  var xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET","http://www.google.com", true);
  console.log('Changed-sending');
  xhr.send();
  state=false;
 }else{
  console.log('Not Changed');
 }
}

function ChangeState () {
 state=true;
}

function getXMLHttpRequest() {
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  return new XMLHttpRequest();
 }else {  
   try { 
    return new(ActiveXObject)("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
   } catch (e) {
    alert("aaa22333"); 
    log("browser doesn support AJAX."); 
    return null;  } }  }
```